# App doesn't cover the entire screen

Tags: android, xml

Although the App that I have created seems to have fit the entire screen on the preview window of `Android Studio`, it doesn't seem to possess the same behavior when I tried running it on my Mobile device.To be more specific, I have a couple of buttons placed close to the Main Navigation Bar which seems just fine in the preview but the one in the phone shows quite some space between the buttons and the `Navigation Bar`.Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Here's the one from the phone]
[image: The Preview]

Here's the XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bletchley.siddharthachatterje.calculator.MainActivity">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/display"
       android:layout_width="370dp"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
       android:paddingVertical="50dp"
       android:text="0"
       android:textSize="35sp"
       android:background="@drawable/tvoval"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/one"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/display"
       android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="1"
       android:textSize="20dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/two"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/display"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="2"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/one"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/three"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/display"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="3"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/two"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/four"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/one"
       android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="4"
       android:textSize="20dp" />
   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/five"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/two"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="5"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/four" />
   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/six"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/three"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="6"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/two"/>
   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/seven"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/four"
       android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="7"
       android:textSize="20dp" />
   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/eight"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/five"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="8"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/seven"/>
   <Button
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:id="@+id/nine"
       android:background="@drawable/pressednum"
       android:layout_below="@id/six"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="9"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/eight"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:id="@+id/zero"
       android:text="0"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:layout_below="@id/eight"
       android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
       android:background="@drawable/pressedzero"
       android:layout_marginTop="29dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:id="@+id/equal"
       android:text="="
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@id/zero"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/zero"
       android:background="@drawable/pressedequal"
       android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="110dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/plus"
       android:layout_below="@id/display"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/three"
       android:background="@drawable/opspressed"
       android:text="+"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="110dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/minus"
       android:layout_below="@id/plus"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/six"
       android:background="@drawable/opspressed"
       android:text="-"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="110dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/multiply"
       android:layout_below="@id/minus"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/three"
       android:background="@drawable/opspressed"
       android:text="*"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

   <Button
      android:layout_width="110dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/divide"
      android:layout_below="@id/multiply"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@id/three"
       android:background="@drawable/opspressed"
       android:text="/"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="110dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/cancel"
       android:layout_below="@id/divide"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/three"
       android:background="@drawable/opspressed"
       android:text="C"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can yo attach screenSort of your device.

Comment: Also paste your layout code here

Comment: I can if you're willing to open a link.I haven't earned enough reputation to be able to display an image alongside the question.Is that okay with you??

Comment: yes , no issue share your link with us @SiddharthaChatterjee

Comment: Abhishek Please Check

Comment: If you are using `Linear Layout` as root element please add weight to your children layout to occupy screen. Or if you are using `Relative Layout` use proper alignment. It will work properly for other screen too (Preview as well as in mobile). Better if you share xml code here.

Comment: Can someone please throw some light on where I've gone wrong in my layout code???

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have specified the static height to those buttons. Better try with wrap content or match parent depends on your design. Try like this and update.